# command line utility that can search recursively for files with a certain suffix, and remove all lines in all files with a certain pattern?

Tags: shell, unix, sed

How do I use `sed` (or any other command line utility) to search recursively for all `.r` and `.R` files, and remove all lines in all files with a certain pattern?

I've seen this command

`sed -i '/"pattern"/d' folder/*`

But this works on all the files in `folder/`, which might miss some stuff, and harm other files I don't want to touch. My directory has a tree-like pattern, and so I need to search everything recursively.

Comment: Have you tried the combination for `find` and `sed`?

Comment: @Pacifist yeah the `-exec` syntax is sort of confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
find folder -name "*.[rR]" -exec sed -i '/pattern/d' {} \;
```

Comment: the lines are still there for some reason

Comment: you don't need to take pattern in quotes

Comment: You can also use `-iname` instead of `-name` to ignore case of `r`. In that case you may use `"*.r"`  instead of `"*.[rR]"`